# alertdialog does not work more than once

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a custom `AlertDialog` and it's layout code is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#ffd200"
    android:gravity=""
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Open"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Copy"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Copy" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Cut"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cut" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_Back"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and java code is like this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lstName;   

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
        lstName = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstNames);        
        String[] names = {"House","car","computer"};  


        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), names[names.length-1].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //lstName.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,names));         
        lstName.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,R.id.textView1,names));


        final AlertDialog.Builder bb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inf= this.getLayoutInflater();
        View menu = inf.inflate(R.layout.menu2, null);
        bb.setView(menu);      



        lstName.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {          
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it's  " + lstName.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                AlertDialog myalert2 = bb.create();
                myalert2.show();                    
            }
        });            
    }           
}
```

after I ran it in emulator, `alertdialog` works with clicking on Items, but by cancelling it with `back` key or touching the dark area, does not work and program will be force closed... 
could you please guide me on this?

logCat is like this :

```
12-13 23:49:26.583: D/AndroidRuntime(6524): Shutting down VM
12-13 23:49:26.583: W/dalvikvm(6524): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa000f180)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3337)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3208)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3188)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:401)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:241)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:353)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:257)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at com.example.mytest31212444.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:49)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-13 23:49:26.653: E/AndroidRuntime(6524):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-13 23:49:27.173: I/dalvikvm(6524): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
12-13 23:49:27.183: I/dalvikvm(6524): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: Move `AlertDialog myalert2 = bb.create();` line from `onItemClick`  after `bb.setView(menu);` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ρяσѕρєя K 's answer was worked for me ... he mentioned it on the comment...

Move `AlertDialog myalert2 = bb.create();` line from `onItemClick` after `bb.setView(menu);` line

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
    lstName.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {          
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder bb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        LayoutInflater inf= MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
        View menu = inf.inflate(R.layout.menu2, null);
        bb.setView(menu);  
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "it's  " + lstName.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        AlertDialog myalert2 = bb.create();
        myalert2.show();                    
            }
        });
```

Comment: I did it but 2 error appeared under `new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` and `.getLayoutInflater();` . errors are : **The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined** and **The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}**

Comment: @MohammadKhandordi Check it now